# Hibernate joined-subclass deadlocks with MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, deadlock

I'm using Hibernate with Joined-SubClasses to Map a class hierarchy to a 
database. Unfortunately this causes deadlocks when an object is updated while a 
different thread is trying to load the same object. With objects that are mapped
to a single table this is no problem. This seems to be caused the way MSSQL
acquires locks on the tables of the class hierarchy.

When Hibernate loads an object from the database it uses a SELECT with a JOIN:

```
SELECT ...
FROM
    subclass
    LEFT JOIN class
        ON ...
WHERE ...
```

When Hibernate updates an object of this subclass it does:

```
UPDATE
    class
SET ...
WHERE ...

UPDATE
    subclass
SET ...
WHERE ...
```

The problem is that if an object is loaded between the two update statements it
causes a deadlock. The SELECT statement seems locks the 2 tables one after 
another. So what seems to happen is:

1. Thread 1 loads an object and places shared locks on both tables
2. Thread 1 executes the UPDATE statement for the class table and upgrades the
   lock on the class table to an exclusive lock.
3. Thread 2 tries to load the same object by executing the SELECT statement, it
   places a shared lock on the subclass table and then waits until the exclusive
   lock on the class table is released
4. Thread 1 executes the UPDATE statement for the subclass table, it wants
   to upgrade it's lock on the subclass table to an exclusive lock, but the
   table is already locked by thread 2, which is waiting for thread 1
5. Thread 2 is aborted due to a deadlock with thread 1

The deadlock graph looks like this: [Deadlock Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImnNC.png)

These object are updated quiet often and this causes deadlocks all the time even
when just a single object is loaded. I also tried to reproduce the problem with
HSQLDB but then it does not deadlock, HSQLDB seems to either lock both tables at
once or waits until it can lock both, so it seems to be a problem that only
occurs with MSSQL.

What would be a solution to avoid this problem with Hibernate without  modifying
the schema (except for indexes)?

Comment: I would leave Hibernate aside to ask your question, this is actually more a MSSQL question than an Hibernate question (and if you tag it appropriately, you'll probably get more traction). Anyway What transaction isolation are you using exactly? PS: don't even try to reproduce the problem with HSQLDB (not sure what version you use but HSQLDB 1.8.2 only supports READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation level so the situation is very different).

Comment: Maybe, but the fact that loading an object creates a join over both tables and that an update of an object creates 2 seperate UPDATE statements comes from Hibernate. If I leave Hibernate out if this, then the solution could be to run both updates in seperate transactions maybe or change the SELECT statement. But that is something I can not do, because these statements are generated by Hibernate.

I first tested with HSQLDB 1.8.x and noticed that it does not work and then switched to 2.0, which delayed the SELECT statement of thread 2 until the transaction of thread 1 has been commited.

Comment: The fact that statements are generated or not is irrelevant, which was my point. Just ask a question about **this** particular scenario (which is correct by the way, running the updates in separate queries wouldn't). But feel free to ignore my advice :)

Comment: I managed to use LockMock.Upgrade in my selects, but that only applies to the base class table, not the subclass table.  So when NHibernate finally attempts to actually update the subclass, there's still a deadlock.  Here's my post on nhusers detailing my finding: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nhusers/6857P97StD8/discussion

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned on the [SQL Server deadlock trace flags 1204 or 1222](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx)?  This will help identify exactly what resources are causing the deadlock.  See the MSDN article on [Detecting and Ending Deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx) for more information.

Are there indexes on these tables?  If so, deadlocks can occur if applications acquire locks on a clustered index then try to acquire more locks on the same table by seeking the non-clustered index.

Comment: I have created a deadlock graph with the SQL Management Studio Profiler and added a graphics of it to the question. On both tables only one row is accessed, and for me it looks like the select statement is locking the two tables in the opposite order of the UPDATE statements. Only one row in each table is accessed. I don't know how an index would help to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that those updates need to be done atomically within a single transaction. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of background on Hibernate so I'll leave it to others to point you in the right direction there.

Comment: They are executed in a single transaction. If they were not they would not cause a deadlock with the other transaction. The activity of both threads is done in one transaction. Maybe I should have made that more clear.